# Multi-Server Setup: Migrating Primary Server

Tags: replication, artifactory

We currently have a Global Enterprise multi-server configuration setup essentially like a Hub-and-spoke architecture: one primary server and multiple proxy servers; the proxies push new artifacts to the primary and pull from the primary as needed.

Our primary server is going offline and we want to reconfigure one of our proxies to be the new primary server. Is there any way (other than Export/Import) to replicate all the artifacts from one server to another?

Would setting the Local repos on the current primary server to replicate to the new primary server work? Why or why not? Thanks!

Comment: If you have an Enterprise license for Artifactory, why don't you address JFrog Support with this question? 

Regarding the question, can you please elaborate a bit on the setup you have? Do you have several repositories that should be replicated across the instances? one repo? what is the size of those repositories? can we assume that you have PRO license on the instances?

Comment: Already done, just waiting for a response from them, but also wanted to check with the community.

Comment: Yes we have several repos replicated across multiple proxy servers, but they replicate to the primary only and then pull as needed to save space on the proxies. On average, the repos are about 100GBs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to migrate all of the content from the current primary to the "new" primary, you can set a push replication from the current primary to the new one. This will allow you to migrate your content from the current primary to the new primary without the need to use the export/import feature. 
You can read more on the 'push replication' feature [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-PushReplication).